# Need Help Setting UITableViewCell's Background Image

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I'm using a background image for my UITableViewCell.

If I just set the background of the cell, but keep everything else the same, I get this:

[image]

I'm if I use this code in viewDidLoad and it fixes the cell but it is making the navbar transparent:

```
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]]; 
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

[image]

Is there way to get the navbar back and get the cell looking normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the most part, I don't believe `UIPopovers` have many visual options as far as background.